# Get the mean of each column of data between multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am trying to create a baseline for data. I need to get the mean of each column from each list, and there are ten lists. Each list has about 50 elements. Taking the mean through each column would give me the average value at that point on the roadway so I need to be careful not to take the average of the list. I am able to grab each column individually by just indexing in the filename loop but that is very inefficient. I would then graph the data using MatplotLib, but that part should be easy. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def graphWriterIRI():
    n = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    # Initialize a new set of lists for each file
        startList = []
        endList = []
        iriRList = []
        iriLList = []
        # Load the file
        if re.search('BASELINE',filename):
            with open(filename, 'rU') as file:
                for row in csv.DictReader(file):
                    try:
                        startList.append(float(row['Start-Mi']))
                        endList.append(float(row['  End-Mi']))
                    except:
                        startList.append(float(row['Start-MP']))
                        endList.append(float(row['  End-MP']))
                    try:
                        iriRList.append(float(row[' IRI R e']))
                        iriLList.append(float(row['IRI LWP ']))
                    except:
                        iriRList.append(float(row[' IRI RWP']))
                        iriLList.append(float(row['IRI LWP ']))

        print iriRList[0] # prints column[0] of the list but I need this for 50 rows and two lists.
```

Here is a bit of the data that I am bringing into the code:

```
Start-Mi      End-Mi      IRI LWP   IRI R e
  194.449   194.549          80.3      87.4
  194.549   194.649          85.3      91.1
  194.649   194.749          87.4      95.6
  194.749   194.849          83.6      72.5
  194.849   194.949          73.7      81
  194.949   195.049          85.2      87.2
  195.049   195.149          106.3    111.5
  195.149   195.249          84.2      92.4
  195.249   195.349          95.5     95.5
  195.349   195.449          60.1      67.2
  195.449   195.549          56.6     51.3
  195.549   195.649          80.6      74.4
  195.649   195.749          73.7      69.9
  195.749   195.849          49.6      48.1
  195.849   195.949          48.1      50.2
  195.949   196.049          53.3      45.2
  196.049   196.149          55.8      45.8
  196.149   196.249          46.7      48.1
```

What I am trying to do in particular is get the average of the columns in the  iriRList and iriLList for each file, and each file is a list.

Comment: You have an ```iriRList``` for each file and you wand the average of column i from each file?

Comment: Yes I have a iriRList and an iriLList and I need to the average of each corresponding data point in each file. Here are a few of the text files that I uploaded to github. https://github.com/thomasawolff/verification_text_data. I am using the baseline datasets.

Comment: So I need the average of all data points between the files at mile point 194.449 and 194.549 and so on etc.

Comment: But each file is a list and the lists we are using are iriRList and iriLList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin function [zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) will transpose a *sequence of sequences*.  You can use it to make tuple for each column.  I'm not sure how you have all your data structured but this is the idea:

```
>>> one = [1,2,3,4]
>>> two = [2,3,4,5]
>>> three = [3,4,5,6]

>>> for column in zip(one, two, three):
    print(column, sum(column), sum(column) / 3.0)


((1, 2, 3), 6, 2.0)
((2, 3, 4), 9, 3.0)
((3, 4, 5), 12, 4.0)
((4, 5, 6), 15, 5.0)
>>>
```

---

If you accumulate the lists from each file:

```
def graphWriterIRI():
    n = 0
    iRlists = []
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        ...
        ...
        print iriRList[0]
        iRlists.append(iriRList)
```

You would use it like this:

```
>>> for column in zip(*iRlists):
    print(column, sum(column), sum(column) / float(len(iRlists)))


((1, 2, 3), 6, 2.0)
((2, 3, 4), 9, 3.0)
((3, 4, 5), 12, 4.0)
((4, 5, 6), 15, 5.0)
>>>
```

Comment: well I think one problem I have is that I cant differentiate between one list and another.

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: I like where you are going with this though

Comment: I have to go to a meeting ill be back in about 30 - 45 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @hollow_Victory - you will have to [catch the TypeError](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect it to see what it is - if it is a list or a tuple or any [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) it should work.

Comment: Ok I got it to run but its just outputting a continuous dataset. I don't think its transposed at all.

Comment: I ended up making a different function for each text file which returned both the right and left IRI data as a list. I then zipped each function call and average them using np.average. Worked great thank you for the advice!

Comment: @hollow_Victory, I thought about providing a numpy solution but it didn't look like you wanted something like that.